# How can I add dbmigration in docker file

Tags: abp

I want to add DB migration also in my docker build image as as first step and then I want to up my application.

Answer (score 1):

It is a console application and you can use the aspnet:7.0 base image.

Here is a sample how you can create an image on your local machine with sdk installed:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
COPY bin/Release/net7.0/publish/ app/
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.DbMigrator.dll"]
```

You need to run `dotnet publish -c Release` in your DbMigrator folder to populate the release folder.